# Using Javascript to change css

Tags: javascript, css, comparison

I am making a battleships game which revolves around a table with a unique ID for each cell, where ships are placed. I want to place three boats that do not overlap, and cannot see an easy way of doing this without major reworking of my code. Can you see an easier way of checking if a boat is overlapping, and then recolouring the cells on the table accordingly? If there is a quick solution to comparing the boats as I have written the code then tell me, if it requires a different structure, give me advice on how it should look. Here is the code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var yLocation = 0;
var xLocation = 0;
var boat1 = " ";
var boat2 = " ";
var boat3 = " ";
var count

function getCoordinate() {
        yLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        xLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 101);

        boat1 = "cell_" + xLocation + "_" + yLocation;
        document.getElementById(boat1).style.backgroundColor = "brown";

        xLocation = xLocation + 1;
        boat1 = "cell_" + xLocation + "_" + yLocation;
        document.getElementById(boat1).style.backgroundColor = "brown";

        xLocation = xLocation + 1;
        boat1 = "cell_" + xLocation + "_" + yLocation;
        document.getElementById(boat1).style.backgroundColor = "brown";

        //boat 2

            yLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            xLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 101);

            boat2 = "cell_" + xLocation + "_" + yLocation;
            document.getElementById(boat2).style.backgroundColor = "brown";

            xLocation = xLocation + 1;
            boat2 = "cell_" + xLocation + "_" + yLocation;
            document.getElementById(boat2).style.backgroundColor = "brown";

            xLocation = xLocation + 1;
            boat2 = "cell_" + xLocation + "_" + yLocation;
            document.getElementById(boat2).style.backgroundColor = "brown";

        //boat 3

        yLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        xLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 101);

        boat3 = "cell_" + xLocation + "_" + yLocation;
        document.getElementById(boat3).style.backgroundColor = "brown";

        xLocation = xLocation + 1;
        boat3 = "cell_" + xLocation + "_" + yLocation;
        document.getElementById(boat3).style.backgroundColor = "brown";

        xLocation = xLocation + 1;
        boat3 = "cell_" + xLocation + "_" + yLocation;
        document.getElementById(boat3).style.backgroundColor = "brown";
}
```

Comment: Leverage css classes for your styles. Specifically since I they are all the same.

Comment: Your code should be scaleable, use an array of boats instead of a standalone variable fo each one. This way you can iterate your array for each boat. As said above, use classes for changing appearance. An html element can use multiple classes.